# Converting Js to Ts error cannot find module

Tags: javascript, typescript

Currently converting my project from JS to TS, working on the server side. Here is the error code.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 
'/Users/steven/Documents/codingDojo/Mern/tomrotten/server/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
(internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

here are a list of my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.58",
"bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"express-session": "^1.17.1",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
"mysql": "^2.18.1",
"mysql2": "^2.2.5",
"sequelize": "^6.5.0",
"sqlite3": "^5.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because it is missing a dependency, either because the dependency is not imported, or it is but it isn't installed. Do you have `import cjr from "cjr"` or something like that at the top of `server/index.js`? Have you done `npm install`?

Comment: I put my dependencies I hope that helps and thank you for the help!

Comment: Try `npm install --save cjs` maybe?